# Array not initialized properly

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I went searching on this forum for someone having a problem similar to mine and I was not able to find why on earth my program is not working properly besides looking solid. I'm just starting to learn Java so I'm not sure if there is some kind of syntax error going on here or if it's more but I have been staring at it, and this website for the past hour and I'm not seeing what's wrong.

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, n, change, i, operations, choice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to add your own numbers?");
        System.out.println("enter '1' for no and '2' for yes");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            int[] array = {
                5,
                7,
                3,
                9,
                1,
                0,
                6
            };
            n = 7;
        } else if (choice == 2) {

            System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add to the" +
                "Array? (Add up to 10)");
            n = input.nextInt();

            int array[] = new int[n];

            System.out.println("Input " + n + " integers");

            for (a = 0; a < n; a++) {
                array[a] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Bubble Sort operation:");

        for (a = 0; a < (n - 1); a++) {
            System.out.print("iteration " + (a + 1) + ": ");

            for (b = 0; b < n - a - 1; b++) {
                if (array[b] > array[b + 1]) {

                    change = array[b];
                    array[b] = array[b + 1];
                    array[b + 1] = change;
                    operations++;

                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.print("Finished array after bubble sort: ");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This operation took " + operations + " cycles");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It's just a simple bubble sort program but I'm seriously stumped here. Any ideas what would be wrong? The error says that `n` is never initialized.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: It's saying that n was not initialized

Comment: In addition, it's not recognizing that the array in the loop is the same as the arrays initialized in the if statement

Comment: These are issues that a debugger assists in identifying. It would be a good idea for you to start using one now.

Comment: simply initialize the value of n and voila error is gone.

Comment: I'm not sure if the debugger in netbeans is any good but it's not really telling me what the issue is. n is clearly initialized in the beginning of the program, but for some reason it's not realizing that within my for loop. I also give n a value within both if statements

Comment: you have not initialized n anywhere besides if block, Compiler consider the scenario in case your block is not executed at compile time. so it is giving n was not initialized.

Comment: Also i don't see any use of it.
if (choice == 1) {
    int[] array = {5,7,3,9,1,0,6} ;
    n = 7 ;     
}
array won't be visible outside if block
same problem with your else if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler is telling you this because the variable `n` might not be initialized.

"But I did! I wrote `n = 7;` and `n = input.nextInt();`! Isn't this called 'initialization'?" you asked. You are completely correct! You did initialize `n` in those places. However, according to your code, `n` will only be initialized if `choice` is 1 or 2. What if `choice` is 3? Or -999? If that is the case, `n` will not be initialized, right?

Let's say that `choice` is -999. The two if statements will be skipped and execution comes straight to the bubble sort part. After that is executed, it comes to this code:

```
    System.out.print("Finished array after bubble sort: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This operation took " + operations + " cycles");
    System.out.println();
```

and it says,

> Waaaaait a minute, that for loop says I need to compare `i` with `n` to decide whether the loop should continue to be executed. But I don't even know what the f**k `n`'s value is!

That's why it complains about this.

**How to solve this problem:**

This depends on whether you treat other numbers as invalid input. If you do, you can write an else clause to the if statement

```
else {
    System.out.println("Input Invalid. Program will now exit.");
    return;
}
```

If you want to treat other numbers as if the user have entered 2, change the `else if` clause to else. Or you can just write

```
n = 0;
```

at the beginning.

Also, I noticed that you have another error. In the if statement, you wrote this:

```
int[] array = {
     5,
     7,
     3,
     9,
     1,
     0,
     6
};
```

and this:

```
int array[] = new int[n];
```

These two arrays will not be accessible outside the if statement. I think you only need to declare one array outside of the if statement, like this:

```
int[] array =  {
     5,
     7,
     3,
     9,
     1,
     0,
     6
};
if (choice == 1) {
    // The original declaration should be removed
    n = 7;
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I put the n = 0 in and then refreshed the program and it worked. then I came back here to say something and I saw that you reccomended it! haha. I  also meant to add in that part about exiting if the number isn't 1 or 2.Thank you! Now I just need to figure out why the program doesn't like my array only when I choose option 1. I don't want to hard code in each value one at a time like array[0] = 5 array[1] = blah blah blah. lists/arrays in java are a nightmare compared to python.... and you're quicker than me again! Thanks so much for your help you're saving my grade here